# RubyMine - Keyword 'require' shown red, but application works fine

Tags: ruby, rubymine, undefined-symbol

I have a simple Ruby SOAP application:

```
require 'savon'
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'https://valid.wsdl.url.here', log: true)
# more code
```

I am RubyMine and Ruby beginner so, please, forgive me any obvious mistakes. (Although I know IDEA and Java quite well.)

I installed Ruby (using Homebrew on Mac, and RubyInstaller on Windows8) and Savon using `gem install savon --version '~> 2.0'`.

My issue is that `require` keyword, as well as `Savon` class name is shown in red. It looks like unrecognized symbol but mouse hover over `require` does not show any message. But when I run the application everything seems to be working (as well as debugging). It seems to be RubyMine issue only, on Win8 and OSX. Why is that happening?

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dark theme for RubyMine uses red to identify keywords and modules. (I think it might use it for some other stuff but I didn't check.)

`require` being in red is perfectly normal. Errors and warnings should either be underlined or highlighted.

Comment: Looks that you are right... It is misleading because in `Colors&Fonts -> General` there is "Unknown symbol" in red. I thought that is my case, not to mention that red is usually some king of error. What I should have done is also check `Colors&Fonts -> Ruby`. Thanks!

Comment: This threw me waaaay off. My Gemfile looks like it's full of errors.